# How to find out Sql server instance name in TFS 2008?

Tags: sql-server, team-foundation-server

We are using tfs2008 and it was already set up before I started. I want to find out what the sql server instance name is that is used by tfs 2008.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The instance name is by default TFSINSTANCE. If you're running a single-server deployment where the all of the services are running on the same server then the server name would be \\TFSINSTANCE.  You can confirm this by opening the SQL Server Configuration manager on the database server. You should see the SQL Server service which will include the instances name.

**see:** [How to: Stop and Start Services, Application Pools, and Web Sites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668752%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

You can also use the TFSAdminUtil tool to view the connections that are configured. The /view option is the one that will show you connection settings.

```
TFSAdminUtil ConfigureConnections /view
```

**see:** [ConfigureConnections Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb778396%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)